# How to style a list so that it looks like a table, with various line height?

Tags: html, css

I try to have some sort of grid layout on my page:

```
<ul>
<li>blabla</li>
<li>bla bla bla bla bla</li>
...
</ul>
```

style :

```
li {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left
}
```

Trouble comes when an element in a `li` is longer than the others on its line. I had at some point a height for each item (300px) but if on one line all the elements are 100px then there will be a 200 px gap with the next line.

So somehow I am looking to have the same effect as with a `table` : on one line, the height is the height of the tallest item, mixed with this ul/li thing where contrary to a table the number of columns and lines is fixed.

Do you know how to do that ? If possible in pure html/css (html5/css3 ok) and no library

http://jsfiddle.net/mF24t/9/

Thanks !

Comment: What benefit does using a list have over a table? Why not just use a table?

Comment: can't understand. *he height is the height of the tallest item*, yes it is: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mF24t/

Comment: @abhitalks one thing is vertical alignment other is height http://jsfiddle.net/mF24t/2/

Comment: @Danko: oh, thanks. posted answer.

Comment: @MLeFevre "Just use a table" would only be appropriate *if* the content in question is tabular data.  If it's just a list of *things to buy at the grocery store* or a list of *photos I took on vacation*, then a table is an inappropriate choice.

Comment: @cimmanon definitely, hence my comment regarding the context of his data :)

Comment: @Danko vertical-align doesn't work: add `vertical-align: top;` to http://jsfiddle.net/mF24t/6/ and you will see that with a longer list you get items on different lines and "lines in between lines"

Comment: How doesn't work ? How I say it works? What is lines between lines

Comment: @Danko the suggestion of using vertical-align looks good and I would like to see if it can get to something that works. Just using it leads to items lining up on line 1 and on line 2, and in between, you see items that squeeze in the holes in between those 2 lines. see for yourself :)

Comment: I don't understand well your point I was only pointing why the fiddle of abhitalks in the second comment seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `display:table-cell` on `li`:

See demo fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mF24t/4/**

```
li {
    width: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

**Update**:

*Variation 2*: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mF24t/13/**

Use `float:left` (as you insist to use) and clear the float say every 5 items. Use only `border-top` to give a faux table like look. In the fiddle, dotted lines show the actual height (which you can control by min-height).

```
li {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px dotted #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 2px;
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
}
li:nth-child(5n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

*Variation 3*: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/wdbye/3/**

Use `flex-box` if you can. Check http://caniuse.com to see if you could afford it. This will give you the flexible heights that you want.

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

**Note**: Apart from the above mentioned ideas, there is no other way where you can have auto-scaling of height based on content as well as a table layout.

Comment: @Thomas: I never mentioned `float:left` in my answer in the first place! You said in your question this: "*I am looking to have the same effect as with a table : on one line, the height is the height of the tallest item*"; and my answer does exactly that.

Comment: @Thomas: there. i have updated the answer to accommodate your requirements. there is no other way you could meet those requirements.

Comment: Variation does the job ! Thanks, I didn't know this